# Can type new text into an existing Word document in a different color?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word-2013

I have a list of questions to answer and I want to differentiate my answers from the original text. I would rather not have to go back, select my text and change.

Comment: Can you just **bold** or _italicize_ your added text?  That's usually easier than changing fonts, sizes, and colors.  On Word for Windows, you can also try highlighting some text, changing the color, and then highlighting more text and pressing `F4` to have it reapply the last action to your new selection.  It will only be on the last action, and not a sequence of actions though.

Comment: You're right, bold or italics would work. I would rather just do a subtle color variation, but will take your suggestion as an alternative. Thank you for posting.